# Javascript filling dropdown from array based on another value of another dropdown:

Tags: javascript, dynamic-arrays

I have two dropdown's. The 2nd dropdown should filter the data based on the 'value' selected in the 1st dropdown.both the dropdown's are dynamically populated from the backend

Say for example: 1st dropdown you choose any student, the value field of the dropdown contains the student no & based on the  student selection made, the 2nd dropdown should  display the subjects of that particular student. The data to be displayed in the dropdown is added from the backend (mainframe prog's). I've added the student no at the end of the 2nd dropdown data separated by '*'.
I sort the data based on student no from the backend before passing it onto screen

This is my first try at html & javascript code changes(I'm a mainframe developer).Hence I'm sure there is a easier and better solution.
We use a in house tool which automatically generates the HTML.
I just have to give the dropdown-ID , other code such as 'select', 'options' etc is automatically 
generated.
Hence after filtering the data from dropdown2 should be hidden and a new dropdown
should be displayed which does not contain the 'student no' and '*' which i have added.

if student1 is selected from the 1st dropdown 
then the second dropdwon should display 
Subject 1
Subject 2

```
    HTML
<div id="dropdrop1">
<select name="StudentC" size="1" onchange="Change()" id="studentCID">
<option value="ALL">All Students</option>
<option value="0123456789">0123456789 - Student 1</option>
<option value="0023456789">0023456789 - Student 2 </option>
</select> </div>

<div id="dropdown2">
<select name="StuclassC" size="1" id="StuclassCID">
<option value="ALL">All Class</option>
<option value="1111111111">1111111111 - Subject 1 0123456789</option>
<option value="2222222222">2222222222 - Subject 2 0123456789</option>
<option value="3333333333">3333333333 - Subject 3 0023456789</option>
<option value="4444444444">4444444444 - Subject 4 0023456789</option>

<select name=newdropdown  id= "newdropdown"></select>
```

and there is a search button after this, which populates a grid.

```
Javascript

    Change()
{
// text from  dropdown2
var aname = document.getElementById("StuclassCID");
var aopts = aname.options;
var adtext = new Array();
var advalue = new Array(); 
for(i = 0; i < aopts.length; i++)
{
    adtext.push(aopts[i].text);
    advalue.push(aopts[i].value);
}

//copy selected student no from dropdown1

var StuDD = document.getElementById("studentCID");
var Stuno = StuDD.options[StuDD.selectedIndex].value;


//Search for '*' in each string from dropdown2

var i,j,temp,Stunogreater;
var studrop = new Array();
var stunoa = new Array();
var showarray = new Array();
var showvalue = new Array();

var Stunogreater =False;

//Copying 'All Class' text dropdown2

 studrop.push(adtext[0]);

//separate the displayable portion from student no in the dropdown2

for (var i = 1; i < adtext.length; i++)
 {
     temp = adtext[i]; 
     var n=temp.indexOf("*");
     studrop.push(temp.substr(0, n-1));
     stunoa.push(temp.substr(n+1,10));
 }    


while( Stunogreater == False )
{
for(var j =0; j < studrop.length;j++)
 {
   if( stunoa[j] == stuno)    
     {
       showarray.push( studrop[j]);
       showvalue.push(stunoa[j]);
      }
   if (stunoa[j] > stuno)  Stunogreater = True;
  }
}         


//Copy text and value to show in a new dropdown

var sel = document.getElementById('newdropdown');
for(var i = 0; i < showarray.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = showarray[i];
    opt.value = showvalue[i];
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Well i dont know if this code is gonna work as the text environment is currently unavailable untill next week.
And there is a search button after dropdown2 i.e the last dropdown, 
when the user clicks on search. The data in the 'Value' fields is passed on to the beackend
to load a grid.
So basically the backend populates all possible values for each of the dropdown and when the users clicks on search the 'Value' field of each of the dropdwon is used to generate the grid.

Any help is appreciated in guiding me to do this in a efficient way.Please provide code snippets along with your sugesstions as its possible that i might take a long time to figure out what you are tryin to say as i'm new to front end languages.
**PS: I can use only HTML and Javascript (no to Php, Jquery & others).**

Comment: Why *No* to jQuery? It is just JavaScript, isn't it?

Comment: How do you store the subjects (to show in dropdown2) by student? Can't see any related data structure there. Please show us the relevant code from your backend (mainframe progs) that generates it - you might would need to change that

Comment: What does this have to do with CSS?

Comment: If you are new to frontend languages, you may want to reconsider your opposition to  JQuery. As Bergi said, it is just javascript, and it will eliminate many of the problems that will make this a terrible task for you, namely interacting with the DOM.

Comment: You also might find it easier to debug this if you break it into smaller logical parts, so  
1)Detect change in dropdown 1  
2)Get data from mainframe  
3)Clear current elements from dropdown 2  
4)Once Recieved, Add new list to dropdown 2  
I can pretty well guarentee you can find answers for how to do each of those things, (some of which you already have) and those chunks will be much easier to debug than a single change() function.

Comment: The dropdown2 is stored as characters.

Comment: dropdown2 char(100);
dropdown2  = subjectcode       
                      !! ' - '        
                      !! Subjectname      
                      !! ' * '        
                      !! studentno;                                                          dropdown2 is populated from three different variables. All defined as characters

Comment: does dropdown 2 initially contain all possible values?

Comment: Yes dropdown2 intially contains all possible values.

Comment: In that case, would it be viable to simply hide the values not currently being used? that avoids ALOT of problems involved with manipulating the DOM

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19232/discussion-between-prad-and-maxprafferty)

Comment: Hestitant on Jquery for the following reasons: 1.) I have no idea of Jquery - It would take considerable amount of time for me to learn it. 2.) This change is only a portion of the code change on the screen. The actual screen is built on javascript, so there would be a mismatch or something. - I dont want to build the whole screen in Jquery again.
3.) I'm not allowed to download any Jquery pluggin's and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you can simply hide the values not being used, you can do this with a relatively simple check:
http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/SEmwG/
html:

```
<select id="dropdown1">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown2">
<option>1</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
​
```

css:

```
.hiddenElement{display:none;}​
```

js:

```
var dropdown1 = document.getElementById("dropdown1");
var dropdown2 = document.getElementById("dropdown2");
var change = function() {
    alert("here");
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdown2.length; i++) {
        if (dropdown2[i].value.indexOf(dropdown1.value) === -1) {
            dropdown2[i].className = "hiddenElement";
        }
        else {
            dropdown2[i].className = "";
        }
    }
}

dropdown1.onchange = change;​
​
```